# Little confused about the constraint of Injective Functions and Surjective.

Tags: functions, computability

From my understanding,

**A Function is called to be Injective**, if different elements of the first set are mapped to different elements of the second set.

Let set A = {a,b,c} and set B = {1,2,3}

Are the following points correct,

if:

1) f(a) = 1 , f(b) = 2 , f(c) = 3    > The function F: A -> B is injective.

2) f(a) = 1 , f(b) = 1 , f(c) = 3    > The function F: A -> B is not       injective.

Did I cover all the possible possibilities?

**A Function is called to be Surjective**, if all elements of the second set are mapped to some element of the first set.

Let set A = {a,b,c, d, e} and set B = {1,2,3}

Are the following points correct,

if:

1) f(a) = 1 , f(b) = 2 , f(c) = 3 > The function F: A -> B is surjective.

2) f(a) = 1 , f(b) = 1 , f(c) = 3 > The function F: A -> B is not surjective.

Did I cover all the possible possibilities?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, your understanding of injective is wrong. "... some elements of the first set are mapped to some element of the second set" could be said for any function. Why not stick with the actual definitions?

Comment: Sorry, spelling mistake! My bad! But is the rest correct then? @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 1):

Your definitions are wrong.

Your second example says $f(a) = 1$, $f(a) = 2$, $f(c) = 3$.  That is not even a function.  $f(a)$ cannot be more than one thing.

"Injective" means **no** two elements of the domain are mapped to the same element of the codomain.

"Surjective" means for every element of the codomain, some element of the domain is mapped to it.

Comment: "Surjective" means for every element of the codomain, some element of the domain is mapped to it. -> Such that you can not have 1 element of the codomain be mapped to 2 distinct elements of the domain, correct?

Comment: Please answer my comment above if possible

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is all correct. Of course you can construct more functions $f: A \to B$, that are not injective / not surjective.

Your definition of surjective sounds a little strange, but I think you mean the right thing. A function $f: A \to B$ is called **surjective**, if for every element $b \in B$ there exists an element $a \in A$, such that $f(a) = b$.

Comment: no, this is not all correct. In fact, it is mostly incorrect.

Comment: Please explain @IttayWeiss

Comment: Michael's answer is all the explanation required.

Comment: I see - But when its surjective, is it possible to have one element of the codomain being mapped to 2 distinct element of the domain or must it be: each element of the codomain is uniquely mapped to an element in the domain?@IttayWeiss

Comment: @Rymk If $A$ and $B$ are two sets, and $f: A \to B$ is a surjective function, you don't map any any elements of $B$ to somewhere! The function $f$ maps each element from $A$ to an element of $B$. Surjective means, that for each element $b \in B$, you find an element in $A$, which $f$ maps to $b$. That's it. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Not really, still confused wether 1 element of set B can have more then 1 element it is mapped to in set A. Yes or No would be the best to clarify for me @aexl

Comment: @Rymk No, the elements of the set $B$ are never mapped to elements of the set $A$ by a function $f: A \to B$. Maybe you should recall what a function is...

Comment: Obviously not by a function  f:A→B, but by the INVERSE. All I want to know if one element of set B can have more then 1 element its mapped to. Or in other words, can 2 elements of set A map to a same element of set B and be surjective? @aexl

Comment: The answer is yes, just got it! Maybe you should recall your knowledge on functions.. @aexl :)

Comment: @Rymk Note that not every function $f: A \to B$ must have an inverse function. Sure can $f$ be surjective and two elements of $A$ are mapped to the same element of $B$. Consider $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B = \{1,2\}$ and $f: A \to B$ defined by $f(1) = 1$, $f(2) = 1$, $f(3) = 2$, then $f$ is surjective, $1$ is mapped to $1$ and $2$ is mapped to $1$.